# How to delete a sub-branch on git?

Tags: git, github

I created a sub-branch using git checkout -b mysubbranch command. How do I delete this sub-branch?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`git branch -D mysubbranch`

Comment: @TomFreudenberg Do you have a source for that. As far as I know `branch -D` will delete the branch even if it wasn't merged, while `branch -d` only allows deletion if it was merged. It will not cause deletion of the remote branch.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I was completeley wrong, thanks for asking again! Just as a more detail answer I link to this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely